# sharing a jupyter notebook on a server

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I made a jupyter notebook that can read hdf5 files and use some functions to analyze the data. I would like to put this jupyter notebook on a server containing different hdf5 files and make it available for people who are working in other places. An exemple of functions would be to see the expression of some genes in a sample. Those people could open this jupyter notebook and add a list of specific genes to look at. 
I am looking at JupyterLab, but I can see that people can read and modify the notebook. I would like that even if they modify it, when they finish, the notebook is as it was before they opened it. Do you think it is possible to do that ? I think I could do it locally with "read-only" but I don't know how to do it on jupyterLab.

I am a newbie for things related to servers. I will really appreciate your help and suggestions.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

You could supply the notebook via a code sharing resource like GitHub and let them clone/copy/download use it as they see fit via their own resources. This insures they aren't changing your source notebook. And you don't have to worry about computational resources because they can run it where they prefer such as on their own cluster or at a cloud center.

Typically, I'd suggest the MyBinder project at https://mybinder.org/ for what you describe as it lets you share temporary active sessions that launch on remote servers. You set up a Github repository with notebooks and the data or a way to retrieve the data built in the notebook and when the temporary session launches, users can work through your notebook. This way they can extend and modify and run their own data and not change your source notebook. However, the resources are limiting as it is free, see [here](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-much-memory-am-i-given-when-using-binder).

Examples:

- [solve for sediment transport](https://github.com/johnjarmitage/flem)
- [Resolving the measurement uncertainty paradox in ecological management](https://github.com/boettiger-lab/pomdp-intro)
- [A quick introduction to RNAseq](https://github.com/ngs-docs/2020-ggg-298-first-day-rnaseq)
- [bendit-binder](https://github.com/fomightez/bendit-binder)
- [blast-binder](https://github.com/fomightez/blast-binder)

I've seen others use Code Ocean, see an example [here](https://twitter.com/hostmicrobe/status/1197330335534637056).

There are other national/government-funded centers that allow similar hosting of services and resources that can be shared with others. [CyVerse](https://cyverse.org/) is one that is now running in the United States and several place, such as [CyVerseUK](https://cyverseuk.org/) in association with the Earlham Institute, and [elsewhere](https://cyverse.org/new-cyverse-node-brings-easier-collaboration-to-austrian-scientists). They offer notebooks to be served via their [VICE apps](https://learning.cyverse.org/projects/vice/en/latest/index.html) in their Discover environment. Their resource allows more computational power and storage than the free, public MyBinder service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mercury](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) framework. It is an open-source tool that converts Python notebooks into interactive documents, like web apps, reports, dashboards, slides.

It requires an YAML header in the first cell in the notebook. In the header you define the presence of the notebook in the Mercury (`title`, `description`, `show-code`). Additionally, you can add widgets to the notebook. Widgets are directly connected to variables in the notebook. The variables which values are controlled by widgets should be in the separate cell.

#### The example notebook

[image: example notebook]

#### The example notebook with YAML header

[image: example notebook with YAML header]

#### The YAML header

There are two widgets defined in the below YAML header. The `name` and `points` widgtes have the same name as variables in the code. User can change the widgets values, click `Run` and the notebook will be executed with new values.

```yaml
---
title: My notebook
description: Notebook with plot
show-code: False
params:
    name:
        input: text
        label: What is your name?
        value: Piotr
    points:
        input: slider
        label: How many points?
        value: 200
        min: 10
        max: 250
---
```

#### The Web Application from Notebook

[image: Jupyter Notebook converted to Web App]

The final notebook after execution can be downloaded as standalone HTML or PDF file.

#### Deployment

The `Mercury` framework is built on top of [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). It can be deployed on any machine with Python available. The deployment for Heroku is very simple, and can be done with two commands (you need to have Heroku CLI tool):

```
heroku create my-amazing-web-app-name-here
git push heroku main
```

Please make sure that there is `Procfile` created for Heroku deployment with:

```
web: mercury run 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

You can also deploy Mercury with `docker-compose`. Please check the [docs](https://mercury-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploy/deployment/) for more details. You can also check the article on how to [share Jupyter Notebook with non-programmers with Mercury tool](https://mljar.com/blog/share-jupyter-notebook/).

Answer (score 0):

You can install a local Gitlab server instead of publishing on Github. Then publish your Jupyter notebooks in Gitlab. Share your server URL with people. Our company is running all internally.